# Calculate Your Salary - Feeling Alone

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, salary-calculator

It is a very good feature and I really appreciate the Stack Overflow team, this is how I felt the moment I saw the "Calculate Your Salary" feature. Unfortunately it was not for me because I live in Dubai.

When I try to use, the form it said this to me:

> "We currently only have salary estimates for the United States, Canada, the United Kingdom, France, Germany, Australia, Brazil, India, Netherlands, Poland, Russia, Spain and Sweden."

I felt that "Ohh I am alone". I have been using Stack Overflow for 2.7 years and usually try to follow all of the instructions of Stack Overflow. I try to give quality answers where I can share my very minor help to make Stack Overflow better.

It hurt me a lot when I realized that this feature is not for me just because of my location.

I would like to request that the Stack Overflow Team does not show these kind of features to those who can't use because them of location etc.

Comment: I don't think you should take it personally, they presumably just don't have enough data from the developer survey for other countries ([see the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/05/developer-salaries-in-2018-updating-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator)). Not showing it to you, or at least not promoting it, might make sense - but what if you wanted to explore salaries in other countries?

Comment: So your feelings got hurt, because Stack Overflow itself does not have the necessary data for the majority of countries in the world and consequently isn't able to provide you the salary calculator?

Comment: @AlexPoole I completely understand and thanks for your point. But as human I had felt and shared. +1

Comment: Well, @Ayaz, when it was first released, there were just 5 countries. Now they've added 8 more. Pretty sure that once they get the data they'll start adding it.

Comment: @BhargavRao Motivational Point. Thank you so much +1

Comment: I totally feel your pain... I live in Uruguay, and having worked on this project, I know I would have loved to see Uruguay in there. There's nothing special on the countries that were included... just that we had enough data to provide estimates we felt comfortable with. If you convince other developers from Dubai to fill the 2019 survey, we'll see it next year on the list!

Answer (score 6):

In many ways we're all alone. It's impossible to provide a catch all for every group of person (or individual) on the planet. There's always aspects that will define us as part of a group and apart from another.

I agree with [@AlexPoole](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373736/calculate-your-salary-feeling-alone#comment628288_373736)

> I don't think you should take it personally, they presumably just don't have enough data from the developer survey for other countries (see the blog post). Not showing it to you, or at least not promoting it, might make sense - but what if you wanted to explore salaries in other countries?

Removing the feature based on location could potentially cut people off from seeing  data. There comes a point where the site has to decide what helpful features to spend money developing and what becomes micro-managing. I fear this is of the second  group.

There's a lot of moderation tools the community has long awaited I suspect (hope and pray) will be on the list before toggling every little feature based on preference or location.

Answer (score 1):

We'd love for the salary calculator to support every country! As mentioned in comments above, it is based on the 2018 Developer Survey data. We hope that each year we can expand to more countries as more people around the world take the survey.

In the meantime, we won't hide the salary calculator in unsupported countries as some might find it useful to see what salaries look like in other countries.